# CORS with webapi asp.net and OData using breeze

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

i have a project in which i have enabled CORS

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:63736");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE,PATCH,PUT,OPTIONS");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept,WWW-Authenticate");
```

call to .../api/login passed ok using jquery how ever when i am trying to query odata with breeze i get cors error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:53809/odata/Metadata. Origin http://localhost:63736 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ward posts some good information on CORS in this post:
[Using Breeze with a WebApi Service from another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629027/using-breeze-with-a-webapi-service-from-another-domain)

Take a look at that first and see if it solves your problem.