# How to enable CORS in odata?

Tags: c#, api, cors, odata

I follow the step below to solve CORS issue.

1.Install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors with nuget.

2.Add code below in WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

Most of API will work. Only oData API will still have CORS issue.

How to resolve CORS problem in oData API?

edit:

After input the code below in Global.asax and it works.

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Request.Path.Contains("odata/") && Context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Context.Request.Headers["Origin"]);
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            Context.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032360/cors-using-asp-net-web-api-2-odata-and-breeze) where it says that you can try to add:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
    "http://localhost:7122/",
    "*",
    "*",
    "DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion"
);
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: USe Fiddler and post a trace of the HTTP CORS traffic and also perhaps post the error in the browser console. Also post your complete WebApiConfig method where you configure the various bits and pieces.