# Problems deploying breeze web api to iis7

Tags: angularjs, iis, breeze

I have created a SPA based on the Hottowel template (angular and breeze). It works fine running it from Visual Studio, but it does not work when deploying it to our iis7. I get 404 for every request to the breeze web api controller. Loading the SPA application it self works fine.

When I try this in the browser:

```
http://company.com/mySPA/breeze/Repository/Metadata
```

I get:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://company.com/mySPA/breeze/Repository/Metadata'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'Repository'.
</MessageDetail>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but there isn't enough information here to help you with your problem.  Consider checking your IIS settings and seeing if you are getting errors when trying to access content.

Comment: Accessing content like index.htm, *.css, *.js and other works fine. But calling actions on the Breeze controller results in 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I divided the project into two separate projects. A Breeze Web API Server and a Breeze SPA Client. I then deployed these as two separate applications, which worked.

This also makes sense in my case, because I want to be able to extend the server with functionality that the current SPA might not use, but future SPA's might.

If you encounter cross-origin issues, read this:

[Using Breeze with a WebApi Service from another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629027/using-breeze-with-a-webapi-service-from-another-domain)